# SQLDeveloper 1.5 and 3+/4+ version different primary key

Tags: oracle11g, primary-key, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-indexes

Someone in my team made a mistake during the development of a software.
The specs have been correctly written, and well reading but the code wasn't good.

The problem was about a primary key... 
The specs have been written by someone who use SQLDeveloper 1.5.1 the developper used the version 3+

But sql developper does not show the same results concerning the primary of table who has more than 4 columns :

We are working on Oracle 11g

Version 1.5.1 : (it shows all the columns)

```
|Index Owner|Columns                                      |Index Name|
|TBI        |CEOPE, CEETB9, NOEXI, NUQCI9, NULDI9, NUSDI9 |PK_THC02  |
```

The spec writter saw 6 columns

Version 3 and the next :

```
|index Owner|Columns                                      |index Name|
|TBI        |CEOPE, CEETB9, NOEXI, NUQCI9                 |PK_THC02  |
```

But when you double click on the line to have the details you have :

```
IndexOwner|Index Name|Table Owner|
TBI       |PK_THC02  |TBI        |
TBI       |PK_THC02  |TBI        |
TBI       |PK_THC02  |TBI        |
TBI       |PK_THC02  |TBI        |
TBI       |PK_THC02  |TBI        |
TBI       |PK_THC02  |TBI        |
```

The developer saw 4 columns and that was the mistake

If you know anything about this problem, it would be great !

Thx for all.

Comment: What is your question? Why your developer made a mistake? I don't think it's clear what the issue is, if there is one.

Comment: Yes this is my question, is there a setting the see everything ?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the information you've described? Where do you only see four columns? Do you have DDL to create the table/PK/index that shows this behaviour, and step-by-step instructions to see what you are seeing?